# Eloquent Models with hasMany WHERE condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm fairly new to Laravel 5.5 and Eloquent, so I'm struggling to work out how to do this using Eloquent objects.

If I was going to do this in SQL it would be pretty simple, but I'd prefer to deal in Eloquent objects.

I have two tables, Lots and Bids and I have the models that go with these.
Is there a way to get any Lot model where a specific user has bid on it (user_id column in the bids table), and then get the maximum bid amount that the user has bid?

Comment: Did you read the querying relationships section of the documentation (i.e. whereHas)

Comment: For some reason I'd completely missed that. I've got it working using whereHas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Devon, I used the [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to return the models that I needed. I then added another method to the model that returned the max bid price.